# How to convert shiny input values into a shiny output table

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that has a lot of input values. I'd like the input values to  be easily perusable and/or exportable so I'd like to put them into a table format.

Previously, I had `data.table(a=input$a,b=input$b,...)` but this is not a very effective way of doing things.

### Aim

Present all input values in a table output in shiny without having to write each input variable by hand

### Background

A shiny input object is of `str`:

```
List of 1
 $ impl:Classes 'ReactiveValues', 'R6' <environment: 0xf798e60> 
 - attr(*, "readonly")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "reactivevalues"
```

- `rbindlist` results in an error: `Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list`
- Similarly `as.data.frame` gets: `cannot coerce class ""reactivevalues"" to a data.frame`
- I then found `ReactiveValuesToList()`which the docs say works like `as.list()` but the object won't convert to inside `rbindlist()`

### MWE

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })

  # This is the bit I'm having trouble getting to work
  output$inputvals<-renderTable({
    as.data.frame(reactiveValuesToList(input))
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100)
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"), tableOutput("inputvals"))
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It works for me.  What versions of `shiny` are you using?

Comment: shiny_0.10.2.2 - will clean up my environment bit and post a full sessionInfo() now

Comment: Full cleardown and it worked, pesky PICNIC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert a reactive object in shiny to a "standard" object in R, use the function `shiny::reactiveValuesToList()` which changes the S6 class into a standard list object.

This can then be wrapped in `as.data.frame` or similar to coerce to a table.